# XCode does not recognize quite obvious C++ syntax errors

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, syntax

I just found that some obvious syntax errors have not been picked up by XCode (version 3.2.3). My application is using a combination of Obj-C (for interface) and C++ (for the rest of the app). Here's an example:

```
class Bike
{
   Bike (Bike &copy, boolean v) { .. }
   Bike (boolean v) { .. }
}
class Data
{
   static *Bike findBikeByID (int id) { .. }
}
```

the call in question looks like this:

```
void function ()
{
   Bike item = Data::findBikeByID (123); // error

   // correct code (Data::findBikeByID returns a pointer, not a reference)
   // Bike * item = Data::findBikeByID (123); // correct 
}
```

Another bug it failed to report is this:

```
void function (Bike *input)
{
  Bike *b = new Bike (*input); // error, should pass 2 arguments 
}
```

the Bike (Bike &copy, boolean v) takes two parameters in constructor. It might got confused with the 2nd constructor Bike (boolean), however even when I specify:

```
Bike *b = new Bike ((Bike &)*input);
```

it fails to notice any problems.

Any ideas why this is happening? Are there any compiler settings that control this?